# Set delegate for textField in ViewController that is owner of .xib

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib, nib

I am trying to use an xib file to display a custom alter view. For that purpose i use the SimpleAlert from [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/simplealert). I have the .xib file with my textFields in it and as the owner of the .xib i set the ViewController is created.

```
import UIKit

class TestBaumViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tfFirst: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tfSecond: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tfThird: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tfFourth: UITextField!


init() {
    super.init(nibName: "TestBaumViewController", bundle: nil)
    initializeTextFields()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //initializeTextFields()
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    //initializeTextFields()
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    //initializeTextFields()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func initializeTextFields() {
    tfFirst.delegate = self // Error Here!
    tfFirst.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable
    
    tfSecond.delegate = self
    tfSecond.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
    
    tfThird.delegate = self
    tfThird.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable
    
    tfFourth.delegate = self
    tfFourth.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var result = true
    let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range , withString: string)
    
    if textField == tfFirst {
        if count(string) > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "BW").invertedSet
            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
        
            let resultingStringLengthIsLegal = count(prospectiveText) <= 1
        
            result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLengthIsLegal
        }
    }
    
    if textField == tfSecond {
        if count(string) > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
            
            let resultingStringLenthIsLegel = count(prospectiveText) <= 3
            
            result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLenthIsLegel
        }
    }
    
    if textField == tfThird {
        if count(string) > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").invertedSet
            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
            
            let resultingStringLenthIsLegel = count(prospectiveText) <= 1
            
            result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLenthIsLegel
        }
    }
    
    if textField == tfFourth {
        if count(string) > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil
            
            let resultingStringLenthIsLegel = count(prospectiveText) <= 3
            
            result = replacementStringIsLegal && resultingStringLenthIsLegel
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

As you can see i added IBOutlets for my textfields and now i wanted to add this view controller as their delegate. So i can check what was entered in the textfields.

I tried different approaches. First i tried putting the `textfield.delegate = self` into the viewDidLoad method but there i get an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" i think that is because the textfield aren't created jet. Next it tried the viewDidAppear method, with the same result. And finally, after i added an Object to the .xib with the view controller class set as its class to get the awakeFromNib method to fire, i put the `textfield.delegate = self` into that method. But i get the same error here.

Is there something i did not think of or am i doing something that will not be working?

regards Adarkas

Comment: can't you set the delegate in interface Builder?

Comment: i tried that but i don't get the prompt to create an delegate, when the blue line is on my view controller code.

Comment: First, I can't reproduce your problem. Your code work fine. Second, in the xib file, select "File's Owner" then in the right corner of Xcode select "Show the identity inspector" then in the class field put the class name of your xib

Comment: ok if the code works fine than maybe the problem comes from the SimpleAlert class i am using. I already have set the File's Owner like you described.

Comment: in Interface Builder select a text field and press `Opt Cmd 6` (Connections Inspector). Drag from Outlets>delegate to the View Controller Object in the View Controller Scene. Does this work?

Comment: Ah that does work. But now i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in AppDelegate.swift when i select a textfield.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have already declared that your controller is conforming to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, do this in the Interface Builder:

1. Select your textfield
2. Show Connections Inspector
3. There will be an `Outlets` section with `delegate` under it.
4. Drag the circle on the right of `delegate` to your View Controller object as shown under

[image]

5. Do this for every textField

The textField delegate methods should be called properly now.

Answer (score 1):

What about didSet?

```
class TestBaumViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tfFirst: UITextField! {
        didSet {
            tfFirst.delegate = self
        }
    }
...
```

Or you can also drag the text fields delegates in the XIB.
Right click on the text field and drag the delegate property to the view controller.

Comment: `didSet` is never called during initialization: _willSet and didSet observers are not called when a property is set in an initializer before delegation takes place._

Comment: This is not initialization.
didSet in called in that case, you can try it.

Comment: well i don't get my first error anymore. But as sone as i click on a textField i get an exception in the AppDelegate.swift file.

Comment: Can you copy / paste the crash log?

Comment: as sone as i find out how i will do it ;).